# SQLAlchemy: How is it that a comma determines if a query returns a String or a Tuple?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, if you put a comma in the query as shown below, you get a "string" back. If you don't put a comma, you get a tuple. Why is so? I can't see anywhere that is explained in the documentation

Using SQLAlchemy0.8

Code below returns a **string**:

```
def get_password(self, member_id):
    for password, in session.query(Member.__table__.c.password).filter(self.__table__.c.id == member_id): 
        return password
```

This returns a **class 'str'**:  `'mypassword'`

While the code below returns a tuple;

```
def get_password(self, member_id):
    for password in session.query(Member.__table__.c.password).filter(self.__table__.c.id == member_id): 
        return password
```

This returns a **class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple'**: `('mypassword',)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the query *always* returns a tuple, but the comma assigns the elements of that tuple to variables:

```
>>> foo, bar = (1, 2)
>>> foo
1
>>> bar
2
>>> baz, = (3, )
>>> baz
3
```

And this also works in for-loops:

```
>>> for a, b in [(1, 'x'), (2, 'y')]:
...     print a, "and b is", b
...
1 and b is x
2 and b is y
```

This is called "tuple unpacking"